# Scheduling local notifications to repeat daily from tomorrow in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification, unnotificationtrigger

I'm trying to schedule a local notification to fire every day (i.e. repeats), at a specific time, but from tomorrow.

i.e "Trigger a notifcation every day at 8pm, from tomorrow"

I've been using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37983437/how-to-set-repeat-frequency-in-user-notification) SO question as guidance, and I believe I am doing what it says but I am still getting a notification today when I run the following code (if I schedule the notification before 8pm for instance):

```
    func testDateNotification(){

    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Test"
    content.body = "This is a test"
    let tomorrow = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: Date())

    let userCalendar = Calendar.current
    var components = userCalendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: tomorrow!)

    components.hour = 20
    components.minute = 00


    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: components, repeats: true)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "test", content: content, trigger: trigger)

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { (error) in
        if ((error) != nil){
            print("Error \(String(describing: error))")
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42892780/2303865 you can use this weekly as start point you just need to remove the weekday date component to repeat it daily

Comment: I believe that's what I am doing when I only set components.hour and components.minute in my code? Although the nextTriggerDate function is useful as it means I can test without constantly changing my system date!

Comment: Don't forget to add a unique identifier.

Comment: I have "test" as a identifier in my code? Or am I missing something? If you look at this quick playground, the next trigger date will always be the end of today, rather than the end of tomorrow:   https://pastebin.com/b6rDvczZ

Comment: You want your notification to repeat daily but you want to skip the first occurrence. I don't think thats possible. there is a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/q/41449749/2303865

Comment: That does seem to be the case! Thanks for your help anyway

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54076050/repeat-interval-for-unnotification/54076269#54076269)

Comment: have you found a solution yet?

Comment: @DominicWilliams Have you got the solution? Pls let me know. I stuck like you.

Comment: My solution was to manually schedule individual notifications for each day in the future for the time I wanted, but you have to be careful as there is a limit on how many notifications you can schedule

Answer (score 0):

`import UserNotifications`

1. Check for user permission

   ```
   UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options:[.badge, .alert, .sound]) {
   if $0 { } }
   ```
2. Add notification

   ```
    let fromDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: Double(0.0))

    let dateComponent = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: fromDate)

    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponent, repeats: true)
    print(trigger.nextTriggerDate() ?? "nil")

    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "title"
    content.body = "body"
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "identify", content: content, trigger: trigger)
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { 
        if let error = $0 {
            print(error)
            return
        }else { 
            print("scheduled") 
        }
    }
   ```

Comment: I have tried with the above code and it is not working as expected as we need to schedule notification from tomorrow. every time "dateComponent" is remains the same. we need to change the component's value for the specific date or +1 .day and if we do above code than the it will repeat on a specific date not date and time.