# Notification with weekly repeat, and specific start date

Tags: ios, swift

I can set a UNNotification to fire at a specific date/time, like so

```
let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute], from: fireTime)
let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: components, repeats: false)
```

And I can set one to fire at a specific time on a specific day of the week, every week, like so

```
var components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.weekday], from: nextMondayDate)
components.setValue(10, for: .hour)
let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger.init(dateMatching: triggerComps, repeats: true)
```

But is there any way I can set a UNNotification to fire at a specific date and time, and then to repeat every week on that weekday and time?

Specifically, I would like to set a notification to fire every Monday at 10am **except** next Monday.

Comment: BTW: Same problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41449749/how-can-i-skip-the-first-occurrence-of-a-repeating-uncalendarnotificationtrigger and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44872429/scheduling-local-notifications-to-repeat-daily-from-tomorrow-in-swift?noredirect=1&lq=1 no simple answers, only possible hacks. This seems to be clearly a missing feature...

Comment: I found this as a soultion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54076050/repeat-interval-for-unnotification/54076269#54076269

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to skip **only** next monday, you can calculate next to next monday date and set in the components on the place of nextMondayDate keeping rest of the setting as it is, like repeat true.

Comment: It doesn't matter what specific date goes in the place of nextMondayDate, because the dateComponents only uses the .weekday component from that date. That's what the repeat is based on. If you were to use the .year .month and .day components, you wouldn't get a weekly repeat.