# Repeat interval for UNNotification

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

There is an option to set the repeat interval for UILocalNotification. Since Apple has deprecated UILocalNotification and recommend to use UNNotification instead, I couldn't find a way to set a notification with custom repeat interval with UNNotification.

```
    var comp = DateComponents()
    comp.year = 2019
    comp.month = 1
    comp.day = 9
    comp.hour = 14
    comp.minute = 14
    comp.second = 0
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let notification: UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
    notification.category = "Daily Quote"
    notification.alertBody = "Body"
    notification.alertTitle = "Title"
    notification.fireDate = calendar.date(from: comp)
    notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendar.Unit.day
    UIApplication.shared.scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
```

So can I set a similar notification that repeats hourly or daily after waiting for the initial notification using the new UNNotification?

Comment: This already has many answers especially when in the context of alarms. Look at the related links when typing in your question, and use methods described in here and related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38380783/usernotification-in-3-days-then-repeat-every-day-hour-ios-10?rq=1

Comment: @Nithin, have you tried my example below?

Comment: @mijokaliger Actually the situation is like I need to schedule the notification for next Tuesday and repeat it every day. I think this could not be achieved with your solution.

Comment: @NithinDevN I've edited my answer

Answer (score 3):

To mimic the UILocalNotification's API `fireDate` and `repeatInterval` you can create two triggers, one non-repeating which would be used for `fireDate` to kickoff and other repeating for `repeatInterval`.

Here's an example:

```swift
import UserNotifications

/// Schedules notificaiton to fire at specific date, and then it repeats by specified repeat component
/// (week, day, hour, etc.) and repeat interval. For example to repeat every 20minutes repeatComponent
/// would be .minute and repeatInterval would be 20.
/// - Parameters:
///   - fireDate: Date for initial notification delivery
///   - repeatComponent: Component by which repeating would be performed (week, day, hour, etc.)
///   - repeatInterval: Interval by which repeating by specified component would be performed. Defaults value is 1.
func scheduleNotification(fireDate: Date, repeatComponent: Calendar.Component, repeatInterval: Int = 1) {

    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Daily Quote"
    content.body = "Inspirational quote."
    content.categoryIdentifier = "quote.category"

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
        options: [.alert,.sound])
    {
        (granted, error) in

        if let error = error {
            print("granted, but Error in notification permission:\(error.localizedDescription)")
        }

        let fireTrigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: fireDate.timeIntervalSinceNow, repeats: false)

        let fireDateRequest = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "quote.starter", content: content, trigger: fireTrigger)

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(fireDateRequest) {(error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error adding firing notification: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else {

                if let firstRepeatingDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: repeatComponent, value: repeatInterval, to: fireDate) {

                    let repeatingTrigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: firstRepeatingDate.timeIntervalSinceNow, repeats: true)

                    let repeatingRequest = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "quote.repeater", content: content, trigger: repeatingTrigger)

                    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(repeatingRequest) { (error) in
                        if let error = error {
                            print("Error adding repeating notification: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                        } else {
                            print("Successfully scheduled")
                            // Successfully scheduled
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    }
}
```

Delegate (for debug):

```
extension ViewController: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        print("\(notification.request.identifier): \(Date())")
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getPendingNotificationRequests { (requests) in
            for request in requests {
                if let timeIntervalTrigger = request.trigger as? UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger {
                    print(Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: timeIntervalTrigger.timeInterval))
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage for your requirement:

```
let interval = 7 // One week from now
if let fireDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: interval, to: Date()) {
    _ = scheduleNotification(fireDate: fireDate, repeatComponent: .day)
}
```

---

***NOTE***

Specifying repeating interval less than 60sec would result with exception:

> 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'time interval must be at least 60 if repeating'

Comment: what is the category identifier? If i have 2 local notification per day should i set different identifiers?

Comment: What happens when I use timeIntervalSince1970 instead of timeIntervalSinceNow? @mijokaliger

Comment: Hmmm. I think the specifics of the code here do not work as intended. I think what is intended is that the `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add` completion handler is called after the delay. And that is then used to schedule the repeating requests after the delay. However, the `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add` completion handler is called immediately. It is the delegate method that is called after the delay. Thus, AFAIK, the delegate method would have to be used to schedule the repeating requests.

Comment: And if you are looking for this to operate in the background, this will not be reliable. The delegate methods are not called unless the user interacts with the notification. See docs in https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate

Comment: In the code, repeatingTrigger's timeInterval is calculated based on present time, but I think present time is irrelevant for repeatingTrigger. That line can be changed like so: let repeatingTrigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: firstRepeatingDate.timeIntervalSince(fireDate), repeats: true)

Comment: Useless approach when app is terminated. The old API from Apple was able to do it. Is there any chance the new UserNotification API can do the same as `notification.fireDate` and `notification.repeatInterval` for a completely terminated App ???

Answer (score 1):

you should use `UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger` 
Check the doc https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/untimeintervalnotificationtrigger