# How to repeat local notification each day starting from tomorrow

Tags: swift, notifications, unnotificationtrigger

I need to schedule local notifications which I'd like to repeat each day from lets say at 23:00. But I do not want to start from today but from tomorrow.

If I schedule them using `UNCalendarNotificationTrigger`:

```
var dateInfo = DateComponents()
dateInfo.hour = 23
dateInfo.minute = 0
dateInfo.second = 0
let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateInfo, repeats: true)
```

then the notifications will be received each day at 23:00 but will get notification for today as well if the above code is executed before 23:00.

Is there any good way to achieve that or I just should schedule 64 (the iOS limit for undelivered local notifications) different local notifications with exact dates?

Comment: See [How can I skip the first occurrence of a repeating UNCalendarNotificationTrigger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41449749/how-can-i-skip-the-first-occurrence-of-a-repeating-uncalendarnotificationtrigger) and the comments below the question. It seems what you want isn't supported.

Comment: Yes, seems it is really not supported right now