# Postpone a repeated notification - is there a better way?

Tags: swift, unusernotificationcenter

I have an app where you specify to get a reminder at a certain time every day to do X to create a habit of it. Then in the app you mark that you've done X today.

The problem I'm having is that if the user marks that they've done X before the notification is triggered, then they still get a notification at the given time. What I would like to happen is that the reminder is skipped today, but then continues from tomorrow onwards at the given time.

My idea to solve this is to set a reminder for each day, 14 days in a row, so 14 reminders. Then if you've done X today, I just remove the reminder for today. And then each day when the user opens the app, I cancel all reminders and set 14 new reminders.

But there must be a better way than setting 14 reminders? But at least 2 years ago, it seems [like it wasn't supported.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55736277/how-to-repeat-local-notification-each-day-starting-from-tomorrow)

Comment: It's frustrating that there is no new information available, but I'm not sure this question and the one you linked need to exist when they seem to be asking effectively the exact same thing as the original question from 2017...

Comment: I guess the question is if there has been any updates so this is possible to do now three years later.. I've searched for hours but not found and info or solution.